# WCF can call method over http but not on https, can browse svc and svc?wsdl

Tags: c#, wcf

I've gone thru almost all answers/suggestions on similar issues I could find and they all make it worse as they break it for both http/https, what I have seems like it is missing some little very hidden thing(lovely WCF) that so far I cannot figure out.

IIS 8.5 on W2012R2, VS2012
symptoms:
- can browse a simple hello html page on http/https root 
- can list svc and svc?wdsl on http/https all cool
- can call any method over http everything is great
- calling the methods over https with the web config below give me:
*500 error: Sendera:DestinationUnreachableThe message with To 'https://<mypath>/<MySvc>.svc/method' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.*

This is my web.config

```
<configuration>

<system.web>
<compilation targetFramework="4.0" />

</system.web>



<system.serviceModel>

<services>
  <service name="Methods.MySvc" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <!-- Unless fully qualified, address is relative to base address supplied above -->




    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Methods.IMySvc" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />


     <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
              behaviorConfiguration="web"      <<<<<< single MISING line!!!
              contract="Methods.IMySvc"/>
    <endpoint address="mex"
              binding="mexHttpsBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />


  </service>

</services>

<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>

  <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>

  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>



<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">

    <!-- serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/ -->

      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>


  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  />
<!-- serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/ -->

</system.serviceModel>


<system.webServer>
<!-- modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/  -->
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"/>
  </handlers>

</system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

**UPDATE:** I answer myself, after digging deep I see the webHttp endpoint behaviour MUST be added to the config file to get the https going thru, just as I though I was just missing a little tiny bity thingie, so my config has now the missing thingie and all is good.